# Find all references and Go to definition not working for a specific project in vs solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, go-to-definition

In a VS 2013 solution with several projects I have added an existing project (dll) and referenced it in one of the other DLLs.
The problem is that when I use "Go to definition" for a class that is defined in this project the text from the metadata is displayed as if the text files of this    dll are not in the solution.
Similar problem with "Find all references".
Language is the same C#.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
When I added the reference of the existing project that I added in the solution I did not select it from the projects of the solution but browsed and select it from its output folder (debug or release).
That simple!